# Cannot install Ubuntu (18.04) on ASUS Zenbook UX580GD-BO001T

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, asus

I just got a brand new ASUS UX580GD, and i am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.

But i can't get past the language selection.

The machine just freezes:
nothing at all responds to mouse clicks or key presses!

How can I setup Ubuntu in my laptop?

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Check that drive settings in UEFI are AHCI, not RAID nor IDE unless you have RAID 0. You will need nomodeset boot parameter. See UEFI section: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Once installed you will need nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Make sure Windows fast start up is off.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for your comment.
I did update as suggested the Bios version, when i went to the Bios Menu.
I dont know if that update UEFI and SSD as well.
i dont see any place where i can do the update anyway.
FYI: i disabled Fast Boot and Secure Boot and i made sure that AHCI is selected for the Hard Disk

I followed the steps on the links that you gave me. and this one https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/uefi

But its not better my system still freezes.

Same thing happens when i try Ubuntu without installing..

Comment: Do not know Asus laptop procedure for UEFI update. My Asus motherboard has three ways to update UEFI, from Windows, from UEFI with update file in a FAT32 partition (I use my ESP) and from a DOS bootable flash drive ( FAT32). Check Asus support page for your model.

Comment: Thanks for your time.
I didnt find anything for my model maybe because the machine is very recent. 
I gave up with Ubuntu. and tried with Debian 9, the setup works fine..
I have problem with all drivers (sound, wifi, hdmi, touchpad..) but at least its installed.

Comment: When system is very, very new, it can take a while before updated drivers are created and then more time before included in latest distribution.  You may have to search to updated drivers or wait for distribution to have latest drivers. When I built my new system in Feb 2016, I had to install 16.04, but knew to either have backups or not rely totally on it until fully released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
Its simple i installed **Ubuntu 18.10**.

First, i tried it without installing => the system didn't freeze. 
*(Sound, WiFi, Touch-pad worked fine)*

Then, when i installed it, and after the first reboot the system freezes after login. *(nothing at all responds)*

I chose to boot on **rescue mode** and executed this command:

`$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Once the installation is concluded, i rebooted the system and we are done.