# Cannot try or install ubuntu on Asus UX580G

Tags: boot, 18.04, 20.04, asus

I am unsuccessfully trying to install ubuntu 20.04 (or even 18.04 for that matter) on a Asus Zenbook UX580G.
I am only interested in long term support versions as this is for a professional environment where I favor stability over new functionnalities.

On ubuntu 18.04, the live CD boots but when installed on hard drive the boot sequence stalls randomly (almost every time but sometimes I can get through on rescue mode).
On ubuntu 20.04, I cannot even boot on the live usb key, either in normal or rescue mode.

I assume the live usb key is fine because I can boot it on an other laptop without problem.
I am suspecting the weird touchpad/screenpad to be the root of my problems, but it's hard to tell because I don't know how to deactivate it before boot.

Any ideas of what I should do or try? any logs to look at maybe to investigate further?

Thanks for you insights!

Edit: 
I am aware of this question, and it looks similar:
[Cannot install Ubuntu (18.04) on ASUS Zenbook UX580GD-BO001T](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097444/cannot-install-ubuntu-18-04-on-asus-zenbook-ux580gd-bo001t) but I cannot use the given workaround (which is: use ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: What is the GPU there?

Comment: it's a dual gpu: Nvidia GTX1050 and  integrated intel

Comment: So boot with `nomodeset` then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6! so the problem still arises after install, but modifying the grub default to boot with nomodeset solves the problem and allows me to move forward

Comment: After install boot again with `nomodeset`, then install the drever and remove nomodeset.